# Convert a json file from server body to a json object in node

Tags: node.js, json, parsing

This should be so simple but I've been stuck on it for more than an hour and it's driving me crazy.

I'm working with an API that's returning data as zipped `.json` files. I've managed to unzip the files, but now need to parse these files to json objects.

The data is in a buffer, and looks like this:

```
{ "name": "foo1", "job": "bar1" }
{ "name": "foo2", "job": "bar2" }
{ "name": "foo3", "job": "bar3" }
{ "name": "foo4", "job": "bar4" }
```

Of course, parsing this with `JSON.parse()` fails because the data is a `.json` file, not an array of jsons.

How can I parse this data correctly? `fs` expects a filepath to read the file, which wouldn't work in my case (as far as I'm aware) because the data is from a buffer, not from a local file.

**tl;dr: How do you I parse a `.json` file that doesn't have a filepath?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the example you provided (where each line is a string representing a JSON object) is not a JSON file.

It’s a file containing multiple JSON formatted strings, one per line.

Without a surrounding array, it is no wonder you cannot parse it.

I’m also unsure what you mean by the data being kept in a buffer.

Do you mean that you’ve read the contents of the file using the standard `fs.readfile()` or variant?

If this is the case, you need to convert the `Buffer` returned from your readfile to a `String`, as in:

```
var contents = fs.readfileSync(FILEPATH).toString()
```

Once you have done so, you could construct an Array using the contents of your file and convert the result to a JSON formatted string using:

```
fs.readfile(FILEPATH, (err, buf) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err
  }

  let objAry = []
  buf.toString().split(/\r?\n/).forEach( line => {
    objAry.push(JSON.parse(line))
  })

  let jsonStr = JSON.stringify(objAry)

  // do something with the result string
  // possibly sending it as a response to an API
  // request as ‘Content-Type: application/json’
})
```

Obviously, you’ll want to add error handling (try/catch) to this.

Comment: I was hoping there's a better way than splitting and adding each line, but if it's not a valid .json I guess this will do for now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

you can change buffer data to `utf-8` charset String then parse it:

```
JSON.parse(buffer.toString('utf-8'))
```

Comment: As I said in the question, the data isn't a json string, it's a **.json file**, which means it can't be parsed by `JSON.parse`.

Comment: @Malfunction so ok. it's a `.json` file. now if you want to read this with `fs` or get it vial `multipart` HTTP request by `multer` its a `buffer` which I assumed its variable name is `buffer`. just get your data in a buffer then do the above.